# If a function is Gâteaux differentiable and the Gâteaux derivative is linear everywhere, is this function Fréchet differentiable?

Tags: analysis, derivatives

In our analysis 2 lecture, we learned that if a function is Gâteaux differentiable, the function might not be Fréchet differentiable. One example we saw was that $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$ f(x, y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x^2y}{x^4 + y^2}, x, y \ne 0 \\
0, x = y = 0
\end{cases}$$

We know that $G(a, b) = a^2/b$ if $b \ne 0$ and $G$ is not linear everywhere so $f$ is not Fréchet differentiable. But does this generally mean if $G$ is linear everywhere then $f$ is Fréchet differentiable?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

No, not necessary. See below from the Wikipedia page [image]